# Do the viewcontrollers in a UIPageViewController set-up need releasing?

Tags: ios5, uipageviewcontroller

I am using the Apple UIPageViewController template from Xcode to create interactive photobooks. Everything works fine except that whenever I turn a page (create a new viewcontroller) the memory allocation goes up and up and up until the app crashes. It looks to me that the viewcontrollers never get 'released' (am I still allowed to use that word in an ARC environment?). It does not seem to be anything to do with the content of the pages because when I comment out all the content creation stuff in the ...DataViewController the memory still keeps going up and up every time I turn a page, not as spectacular as when a large image has been included but it still keeps creeping up.

There's been exactly the same question here: [PageViewController: How to release ViewControllers added to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934348/pageviewcontroller-how-to-release-viewcontrollers-added-to-it) but this one deals with a pre arc & storyboard situation. Adding autorelease is not permitted and it certainly seems that the compiler is NOT taking care of it. :-(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey!!!, i am facing the same problem. In my case, there are three view controllers that keep on playing on page view controller. I had put breakpoints on didReceiveMemoryWarning of each view controller. and when the warning comes. Breakpoint hit these methods on each viewcontroller the no of times the view controllers were initiated. this means they were not being allocated. How to resolve it please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

The problem turned out to be the never enough damned "UIImage imagedNamed" construct. It probably is all my own fault for not checking after I read somewhere that this had been fixed in a recent xcode release. So I assumed images were no longer being cached whereas the opposite was true. Once I changed all to the "UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile" the app started working smooth as a babies bottom.

Comment: Hey!!!, i am facing the same problem. In my case, there are three view controllers that keep on playing on page view controller. I had put breakpoints on didReceiveMemoryWarning of each view controller. and when the warning comes. Breakpoint hit these methods on each viewcontroller the no of times the view controllers were initiated. this means they were not being allocated. How to resolve it please suggest.

Comment: same problem here.
trying to build a child app animating animal cartoon and playing sound.
every animal detail page is loaded into UIPageViewController.
UIPageViewController never releasing memory unless memory warning received.
What do you mean with imageWithContentsOfFile solved the problem ?
i am loading images with imageNamed. May it be the cause of unReleased memory ?

Comment: Thanx Mr. Jigs.
imageWithContentsOfFile did really work
i can not beleive it. i am losing hair for this nearlly for a month.
All of a sudden UIPageViewController started releasing memory.
How different are  imageNamed: and imageWithContentsOfFile: methods ?
How could this be the problem ? How could we guess this?
For more than a month, Looking for this UIPageViewController cache problem .
Points for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem building a picture book with very large images.  I went to other question you provided a link for and that solved it for me.  Adding "`autorelease`" frees up the memory.

In the `UIPageviewcontroller` delegate method "`viewControllerAtIndex`".  I changed from:

```
// Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
ContentViewController *contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContentViewController" bundle:nil];
```

and added autorelease

```
// Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
ContentViewController *contentViewController = [[[ContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContentViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease] ;
```

This wasn't included in the apple example but I'm also using xib for each page.  I've been debugging this using instruments and saw memory reclaimed right away and dealloc being called when it wasn't previously.

found answer here....
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7934392/1212585

Comment: Thank you. But it turned out that this was not the problem.