# page-based with storyboard dont dealloc

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller, imagenamed

I am developing a complete application using the template "page-based storyboard".

But whenever I turn page, I see  thru the instruments that the amount of memory allocated only increase and never decrease, so until a crash occurs.

Trying in iPad device crash too.

To simplify and try to find the problem, I created a test app using the same template and opting for ARC, only loading the image of the pages that I use and no change anything in the original apple code, even in this simple application the problem occurs.

I think the problem is because all page are stay allocated like this issue
[PageViewController: How to release ViewControllers added to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934348/pageviewcontroller-how-to-release-viewcontrollers-added-to-it)

but I m using storyboard, so, where is:
`PageView *pView = [[PageView alloc] init];`

I have:
`MWViewController *dataViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MWDataViewController"]`

I try to put autorelease but no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I was having is that I was using background image in all pages and the `imageNamed:` method caches images which makes my memory footprint grow. I used the `UIImage initWithContentsOfFile:` method and my foot print stayed mostly flat.